# libgdx TiledMap Rendering Performance Issue

Tags: performance, maps, libgdx, render, tiled

So I had performance issues with my libgdx project and I tracked it down to the map rendering.
I isolated the issue by creating an empty project and do as little as possible, just the map rendering. This is the code I came up with:

The Desktop start up project class:

```
package com.me.test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "performanceTest";
    cfg.useGL20 = false; // doesn't make a difference...
    cfg.width = 1080;
    cfg.height = cfg.width/12 * 9; // 810
    
    new LwjglApplication(new Test(), cfg);
}
}
```

The actual Code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class Test implements ApplicationListener {
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap map;
private static  OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

@Override
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);

    TmxMapLoader maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
    
    map = maploader.load("test.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1);
    renderer.setView(camera);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    renderer.dispose();
    map.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    renderer.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

Now the weird thing is: not only is the CPU usage ridiculously high, but it makes a jump when more than 128 have to be rendered. Below 129 tiles the performance is always the same. ( Only this process takes about 2-4% ) But rendering 129 tiles or more takes about 40 - 60%!
Now my question is: why is that? Am I doing something wrong?
I can't imagine the renderer from libgdx would have such a fatal flaw... and making a game only using 128 tiles on screen isn't an option :)

Thanks for any answers or thoughts!

Environment:

- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1
- libgdx version 0.9.9
- Windows 7
- Graphics Chip: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti
- CPU: Pentium Dual-Core 2.70GHz

Rendering 128 Tiles:

[image: Rendering 128 tiles]

Rendering 129 Tiles:

[image: Rendering 129 tiles]

Comment: I am wondering about that. I am currently rendering 40x30Tiles x 5layer= 6000Tiles without any problem in performance. But do you really have a performance issure or just a rise in CPU? So does the FPS drop in any case? Add a FPS Logger and see if it's still an issue. Are all tiles in one tileset? If not do so. They shouldnt be in different tiles since you have texture binding. Since the Map is 1 row more and the whole row does get iterated it's sure that it meight take more performance. Why its such a big difference i dont know. Maybe upload the tmx + asset if possible to check it.

Comment: Well... the problem is, while I have sweet 60 FPS on my computer I have like 20 on my laptop... I wouldn't bother with the CPU, but I don't think it is necessary for the CPU to work this hard. And yes.. I have a 32 x 32 tileset with 16 x 16 tiles

Comment: Good thought on the asset loader... will try it out

Comment: No... loading the Tmx file with assetManager didn't solve the issue...

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution:

Just add

```
Mesh.forceVBO=true;
```

before the app starts.

first of all this is probably a hardware issue. On other computers everything runs smoothly but there have been others that had the same issue. On the BadlogicGames Forum I found the answer more details are there:

[Badlogic Forum Post](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12484)